# Removing a Marker from an array in Google maps v3.0 problem

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got this problem when removing a Marker from an array. I click on the map and place markers where i have clicked, the markers are then saved in an array. When removing them it only works in the order i have placed them but backwards, that means i place 1 2 3 but have to remove them like 3 2 1.

If i try to remove the markers in random order, the first one is removed, but then the others just stop working, the listener still works, but it seems like the forloop doesnt find the other markers in the array.

Any ideas? I'm completely lost.

Here is the code:

```
 var map;
    var tempLatLng;
    var zoomLevel;
    var markers = [];
    var zoomLevels = [];
    var count = -1;
    var nullLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(84.52,45.16);
    var nullMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: nullLatLng, 
    });

    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.605629745598904,13.000441789627075);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel:false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


    //Puts a listener on the map, when clicking on the map, it places a marker.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    document.getElementById("zoom").value = zoomLevel;
    tempLatLng = event.latLng;
    setTimeout("placeMarker(tempLatLng)", 800);     //placeMarker is called with a duration so that                                                         //doubleclicking doesn't bother the placement.
    });

    }
    //Function to place markers.
    function placeMarker(location) {
    if(zoomLevel == map.getZoom()){
        if(true){
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location, 
                map: map,
                draggable:true
            });
            count = count + 1;
            markers[count] = marker1;
            document.getElementById("count").value = count;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1,'rightclick', function(event){
                document.getElementById("test2").value = "funkar";
                for(var i = 0 ;i < markers.length ;i++){
                    if(markers[i].getTitle() == marker1.getTitle()){
                        marker1.setMap(null);
                        document.getElementById("markerpos").value = markers[i].getTitle();
                        document.getElementById("test1").value = markers[i].getTitle();
                        count = count - 1;
                        document.getElementById("count").value = count;
                        markers[i] = nullMarker;
                    }
                }

            });

            marker1.setTitle(location.toString());

        }
        map.setCenter(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: your remove marker is based off right clicking on the marker itself.  everything seems to work fine even if remove marker is at random order. IE create marker 1 2 3, right click on marker 2 would remove it and then 1 3 would work as well.

Comment: would work as you see no problem with the code? did you try it out? Im trying to put it up on a server so that you guys can try it out too.

Comment: @Denis i see the problem now.  If i help you fix the code would you accept the answer by marking the check mark to the answer if it works out for you?

Comment: Sure thing kjy! Just tell me where i do that after the code is fixed :) (first time stackoverflow user)

Comment: @Denis please let me know if you have any question.  To accept an answer hover over the up and down arrow and you should see a check mark that is white filling.  To accept just click on that check mark. Welcome to the community =)

Comment: @Denis also it's custom to use upvote and downvote feature to give "rep" for correct and incorrect answers.  You can give upvote by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer and downvote by clicking on the down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/Bs6rn/)

Basically, you were using `var count` to keep track of the number of markers.  You can do `markers.length` for that.  Instead of using `markers[count]` you can use native array's push method to add element into the array.  To remove use `splice(i, 1);` where i is the element's position and remove 1 element from that position.  Also, to check if two markers are equal or the "same" instead using `getTitle()` use `===` which does:

> is exactly equal to (value and type)

The problem is if you create two or more markers on the same position it would remove both markers but in reality you only remove one of the two "clones" and thus leaving a marker un-removable.  This is caused by using `getTitle` which returns lat lng and if you have two markers w/ same lat lng you have an issue.  Also, i changed, within your `onclick` function, `marker1` to `this` which are referring to the same object for readability.

```
//Function to place markers.
function placeMarker(location) {
    if (zoomLevel == map.getZoom()) {
        if (true) {
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            count = count + 1;
            markers.push(marker1);
            document.getElementById("count").value = markers.length;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'rightclick', function(event) {
                document.getElementById("test2").value = "funkar";
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i] === this) {
                        this.setMap(null);
                        document.getElementById("markerpos").value = markers[i].getTitle();
                        document.getElementById("test1").value = markers[i].getTitle();
                        markers.splice(i, 1);
                        document.getElementById("count").value = markers.length;
                    }
                }

            });

            marker1.setTitle(location.toString());

        }
        map.setCenter(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I totaly forgot about the push and splice functions! Thank you so much for your help! :D i think i marked the check mark too :)

Comment: Thank you! I will spend much more time here :)

Comment: Push and splice is useful when you are adding same markers to map. when markers are added to map based on some events and their data is not similar either, it is not possible to use these functions and markers should have a unique ID. for example, visualizing request to a website from geo locations in past 10 seconds. you need to remove expired ones and add new ones. please note removing all markers and adding them to map again is very heavy process.